"Deducing this" causes `exception specification is not available until end of class definition`, is this a compiler bug?
Consider the following code:
struct A
{
    void foo(this auto &&) noexcept(true) {}
    auto bar() -> decltype(foo()) {}
};

Clang 19 rejects this code with the error below, while GCC and MSVC accept it.
<source>:4:28: error: exception specification is not available until end of class definition
    4 |     auto bar() -> decltype(foo()) {}
      |                            ^

Is this code somehow illegal, or is it a Clang bug? If it's illegal, why? (Why can't the exception specfification be available at this point?)

To be clear, my actual noexcept(...) depends on this, so removing (true) isn't an option.
Also if I start using this in it, GCC starts crashing: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=117106

The return type is not part of the complete class context so not sure if its a bug or clang is the correct one.

auto bar() { return foo(); } is accepted by Clang as well.

I think this may be a version of CWG2335

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/36907
